# Magento local.xml visible when using .htaccess password protection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento

i wanted for a Magento staging system a simple user authentication. So i made the following .htaccess combination. My problem now is that if i enabled this my app/etc/local.xml file is visible for everyone which enters the correct credentials or visits the site from a specific ip-address.

For everyone who is not into Magento. The .htaccess & .htpasswd is in the root folder in the folder /app/ is another .htaccess file with the following content

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

This is the snippet of my .htaccess authentication:

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '127.0.0.1'">
  AuthName "DEV"
  AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
  AuthType Basic
  Require valid-user
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 123.456.789.0
  Allow from 123.456.789.1
  Allow from 123.456.789.2
  Allow from 123.456.789.3
  Satisfy Any
</If>
```

Thank you in advance!

Cheers Tobias

Comment: is htaccess file in `app` folder?

Comment: yes the .htaccess file is in the app folder.